# Android 3D position

Tags: android, position, mapping

I want to map the location of an android device precisely in 3D space.

Accelerometers gave me no luck due to their exponential error growth. 
GPS is too inaccurate for my application.

Does anyone know another way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: On what coordinate system? 3d position in world, orientation, etc?

Comment: XYZ position relative to the starting point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to map the 3D position change of Android phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27913956/ways-to-map-the-3d-position-change-of-android-phone)